# How to mimic ip forwarding in scapy python 3.7 for custom MITM

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, scapy

I am making my own MITM attack using python 3.7 and scapy.
I use scapy to sniff the traffic and I want to be able to mimic ip forwarding using it, like when I recieve a packet with an ip source of the victim I want to be able to forward that packet (or modify it). I can`t use ip-forwarding on linux because I want to be able to modify the traffic. I know that tools like arpspoof and MITMf exist but I want to make my own.